# Magento - Checking if a module is installed?

Tags: magento

I have a small piece of code in a template file that I ONLY want to run if a certain module is installed. I found the below code, which you can use to find if a module is active, but I want to know if a module is installed.

```
$modules = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules')->children();
$modulesArray = (array)$modules;

if($modulesArray['Mage_Paypal']->is('active')) {
    echo "Paypal module is active.";
} else {
    echo "Paypal module is not active.";
}
```

I'm thinking I could maybe get a list of names of all the modules that are installed, and then use

```
if (stristr($modulelist, 'Name_Extension'))
```

to show my code only if the referenced extension is installed.

Anyone any ideas how to do that? Or any better solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$modules = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules')->children();
$modulesArray = (array)$modules;

if(isset($modulesArray['Mage_Paypal'])) {
    echo "Paypal module exists.";
} else {
    echo "Paypal module doesn't exist.";
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is gonna do the trick. I'll test a little more first so won't accept as the answer just yet, but definitely looking good.

Comment: So there are several states for modules mentioned in this question (`installed` vs `active` vs `enabled`). I actually like @baoutch's answer better for enabled, but I don't think that's what OP was asking for? Anyway, it was over four years ago, so there ya go :)

Answer (score 89):

There's a core helper for that:

```
Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('MyCompany_MyModule');
```

It's in `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`.

There's also a `isModuleOutputEnabled()` method to check if output of module is disabled in System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Disable Modules Output.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Not only checks that it is installed but if it is enabled.

Comment: With the comment above, I also agree.  However let me emphasize that through the core helper function the Magento Core Team has made a contract with developers such that whatever implementation changes they make under the hood, this method will always work no matter what.  This is not so with the solutions that rely on parsing out the configuration XML hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to find if a module is installed but disabled is with:

```
if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('advanced/modules_disable_output/Mage_Paypal')) {
    echo "Paypal module is installed";
}
```

**Edit**
Have just realised a version of this - using the little known `ifconfig` - could show a block only if another module is disabled. eg.

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block ifconfig="advanced/modules_disable_output/Mage_Paypal" type="core/template" template="sorry/this/is/unavailable.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Cheers for this - no use in this case in particular, but again might come in handy in the future...

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a module exists on installation using this snippet `Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules/Mage_Paypal')` returns FALSE if does not exist

Answer (score 1):

in the declaration of your module, try adding a `depends` element, like on [this page](http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/08/31/magento-module-configuration-file-reference.html).
This will probably raise an exception, which you could handle with a try/catch block.

Comment: Little more complex than the above, but can see it also working too. Thanks for posting, as I'm sure this will also be useful in the future...

Answer (score 0):

In any class, model, controller or even PHTML you can call and it will work.

Data.php

```
class Company_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract 
{ 
  const XML_PATH_GEN_ENABLE = 'Section/Group/Field';
  public function isEnable() 
  {
    return Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(XML_PATH_GEN_ENABLE,Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
  } 
}
```

You can call using below code `Mage::helper('module_name')->isEnable()`

Your config file is like

config.xml

```
<global>
  <helpers> 
    <module_name> 
      <class>Company_Module_Helper</class> 
    </module_name> 
  </helpers>
  // Another Necessary Code for this extension
</global>
```

Comment: Data.php
<?php
class COMPANYNAME_MODULENAME_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
 const XML_PATH_MM_BESTSELLER_GEN_ENABLE     = 'SECTIONNAME/GRPUPNAME/FIELDNAME';
 
 public function isEnable()
 {
  return Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_MM_BESTSELLER_GEN_ENABLE,Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
 }
}?>

you can call using below code
Mage::helper('module_name')->isEnable()

and your config.xml like
<global>
..blah blah...
    <helpers>
      <module_name>
        <class>COMPANYNAME_MODULENAME_Helper</class>
      </module_name>
    </helpers>
..blah blah...
  </global>

Comment: Please [edit your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31977905/edit), add the code, and format your code properly. It's difficult to read code in the comments.